# How to model a weak entity in sql

Tags: mysql, sql, oracle-sqldeveloper

I am new to databases in general and currently just trying stuff out.

I am trying to model a basic hotel system in SQL

So my plan is as follows.

A Hotel has many rooms and a room has a room number which is `unique` within a hotel. I understand this is a weak entity

When a guest creates a booking, a room is assigned to that guest.

So I came up with the following create statements to create the database

```sql
CREATE TABLE Hotel (
  hotel_id int PRIMARY KEY,
  name varchar(255),
  stars int
);

CREATE TABLE Room (
  room_number int,
  capacity int,
  hotel_id int
);

CREATE TABLE Guest (
guest_id int PRIMARY KEY,
name varchar(255),
hotel int,
room int
);

ALTER TABLE Room ADD FOREIGN KEY (hotel_id) REFERENCES Hotel (hotel_id) ON DELETE CASCADE;

ALTER TABLE Guest ADD FOREIGN KEY (hotel) REFERENCES Hotel (hotel_id);

ALTER TABLE Guest ADD FOREIGN KEY (room) REFERENCES Room (room_number);
```

I get the error `no matching unique or primary key for this column-list`

I guess it's because of the fact that room_number is no primary key.

My problem is that if I make it a primary key, that I cannot have two rooms at different hotels with the same room number as a primary key is unique

How can I fulfill the requirement that room is a weak entity but still have unique room numbers within a hotel.

I take it I am missing something. Help greatly appreciated

Comment: Create columns hotel_id in room and room_id in guest. No need for hotel_id in guest you have it through room.

Comment: You can create a composite primary key, so in `Room` this would be `hotel_Id` **and** `room_number`, so you can have the same room number multiple times as long as it in a different hotel. You can also have composite foreign keys, so any reference to `room` would require `room_number` and `hotel_id` in the referencing table. After a while this can get messy if you have a child table which references two or more composite keys, and you end up with a key contains 10 columns. At this point it may be an idea to switch to using surrogate keys and just use a unique index to ensure no duplicates

Comment: I would think Guest is separate from a Room, and you need a reservation.  What happens when a guest stays in multiple rooms over time?

Comment: @OldProgrammer. I agree with you about that. The model I posted was just a section of what I was planning to show my problem and will implement that at a later stage.

Answer (score 0):

Create a primary key that is a combination of hotel_id and room_number.

```
CREATE TABLE Hotel (
  hotel_id int PRIMARY KEY,
  name varchar(255),
  stars int
);

CREATE TABLE Room (
  room_number int,
  capacity int,
  hotel_id int,
  PRIMARY KEY (room_number, hotel_id)
);

CREATE TABLE Guest (
guest_id int PRIMARY KEY,
name varchar(255),
hotel int,
room int
);

ALTER TABLE Room ADD FOREIGN KEY (hotel_id) REFERENCES Hotel (hotel_id) ON DELETE CASCADE;

ALTER TABLE Guest ADD FOREIGN KEY (hotel) REFERENCES Hotel (hotel_id);

ALTER TABLE Guest ADD FOREIGN KEY (room, hotel) REFERENCES Room (room_number, hotel_id);
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a primary key for the `rooms` table based on an identifier other than the `room_number` and then have a `bookings` table as guests can make multiple bookings:

```sql
CREATE TABLE Hotels (
  id    INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  name  VARCHAR(255),
  stars INT
);

CREATE TABLE Rooms (
  id          INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  hotel_id    INT,
  room_number INT,
  capacity    INT,
  CONSTRAINT rooms__hi_rn__u UNIQUE(hotel_id, room_number)
);

CREATE TABLE Guests (
  id       INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  name     varchar(255)
);

CREATE TABLE Bookings (
  id             INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  guest_id       INT,
  room_id        INT,
  check_in_date  DATE,
  check_out_date DATE
);

ALTER TABLE Rooms ADD CONSTRAINT rooms__hi__fk
    FOREIGN KEY (hotel_id) REFERENCES Hotels (id);

ALTER TABLE Bookings ADD CONSTRAINT bookings__gi__fk
    FOREIGN KEY (guest_id) REFERENCES Guests (id);

ALTER TABLE Bookings ADD CONSTRAINT bookings__ri__fk
    FOREIGN KEY (room_id) REFERENCES Rooms (id);
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=f37cd98be622fa37a855408beecc1a2a)*